# How can I move this down?

Tags: html, css

I have submit and reset buttons for a form, and I cant for the life of me figure out how them to get under the textbox. And then the address element is displaying on the right side aswell.

[image: submit/reset buttons problem]

```
<label id="warranty">
<input type="checkbox" name="warranty" />
Yes, I want the 24-month extended warranty
</label>



<label for="request" id="request">Any special requests on your order?</label>
<textarea name="request" id="request"></textarea>


<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" />
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" />   

</form>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {
display: inline-block;
width: 150px;
float: inline;
}
```

Surely I'm missing something right?

Comment: `float: inline;` isn't valid. And IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
#request { display: block; clear: both; }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hxwzy/)

Comment: Very useful, the only thing I cant seem to get is that my submit and reset buttons are appearing on seperate lines, where they should be together on the same line.

Comment: The buttons on your page look different than those in the above fiddle? Does removing 'float:inline' and changing 'inline-block' to 'block' fix anything?

Comment: Negative. Infact if I remove inline-block, it puts them back on the side again instead of under.

Answer (score 0):

How about a line break after the textarea?

ie:

```
<label for="request" id="request">Any special requests on your order?</label>
<textarea name="request" id="request"></textarea>
<br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" />
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
```

or via css, you could make the first of the 2 buttons clear any previous floats;

```
input[type="submit"] {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display: inline-block;` try `display: block;` for either your text area (doing this will say "put nothing else on the the same line as this element unless it floats", or for your submit order and cancel buttons.

I'd also suggest putting your two buttons inside of a wrapper div so that way you can manipulate the position of those two buttons as a unit instead of individually.

Also, one last note: don't have more than one element on a page with the same id. For elements you want to apply the same properties to, make the id a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div to wrap them.
I don't see "address element", so I can't help you.

```
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" />
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" />   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aWcXB/)!

```
<form>
  <label id="warranty">
  <input type="checkbox" name="warranty" />
  Yes, I want the 24-month extended warranty
  </label>
  <label for="request" id="request">Any special requests on your order?</label>
  <div class="clear:both"></div>
  <textarea name="request" id="request"></textarea>
  <div class="clear:both"></div>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Order" />
  <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />   
</form>
```